# Trouble Installing Firebase Tools via npm Behind a Proxy - ENOTFOUND error

Tags: flutter, npm, proxy, firebase-tools

I'm facing an issue while trying to install Firebase Tools using npm. I'm running the command npm install -g firebase-tools, but I keep getting an ENOTFOUND error. Here's the error message I'm encountering:

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tools failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases, you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

I've checked my network settings and I am indeed behind a proxy. I've also tried configuring the proxy settings using the npm config command, but the issue persists. Here's what I've tried so far:

Ran npm config set proxy http://my-proxy-server:my-proxy-port
Ran npm config set https-proxy http://my-proxy-server:my-proxy-port
Verified the proxy settings using npm config list
Despite these steps, I'm still unable to install Firebase Tools. Could anyone guide me on how to properly configure npm to work behind a proxy and successfully install Firebase Tools? Are there any additional steps or configurations I might be missing?

Thank you for your assistance!

I attempted to install Firebase Tools using the npm command npm install -g firebase-tools on my Windows PC. I am behind a proxy network, so I also tried configuring the proxy settings using the npm config command. Here are the steps I followed:

Ran npm config set proxy http://my-proxy-server:my-proxy-port
Ran npm config set https-proxy http://my-proxy-server:my-proxy-port
Verified the proxy settings using npm config list
What I Expected:

I expected that after configuring the proxy settings, the installation of Firebase Tools would proceed without any issues. I anticipated that npm would recognize the proxy configuration and successfully download the required packages from the npm registry.

What Actually Resulted:

Despite configuring the proxy settings as mentioned above, I continued to encounter an ENOTFOUND error during the installation process. The specific error message is as follows:

npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/firebase-tools failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.example.com
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases, you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Despite verifying that the proxy settings were configured correctly using the npm config list command, the issue persisted, preventing me from installing Firebase Tools.